# Column in pandas dataframe with None and numbers can't be modified

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating a pandas dataframe from a list of dictionaries. One column in the dataframe can
contain both None values and numeric values. I am trying to change the cells with None to a default value (below is 10.0).

I am not understanding why the first of the two ways does not work while the second one works. I hope any pandas expert can help me.

```
## Creation of pandas dataframe
t = [{'Key1':None,'OtherKey':2, 'AnotherKey':'whatever'},{'Key1':2,'OtherKey':3, 'AnotherKey':'whenever'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(2), columns=['Key1','OtherKey','AnotherKey'])
idr = 0
for r in t:
    df.iloc[idr]=r
    idr += 1
```

I would like to change the `None` value in the `Key1` column to the default value of 10. The lines below

```
df.loc[df['Key1']==None,'Key1']=10.0
print(df)
```

returns

```
   Key1 OtherKey AnotherKey
0  None        2   whatever
1     2        3   whenever
```

while this method

```
df.loc[df['Key1'].isnull(),'Key1']=10
print(df)
```

returns as expected:

```
  Key1 OtherKey AnotherKey
0   10        2   whatever
1    2        3   whenever
```

Any expert that can explain me the difference between the two methods? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One creadit to our fellow's answer above. To add, in my experience, it is always better to run `df.info()` first. In your case, `Key1` columns is `objective` which will potentially causes certain unnecessary errors later while your manipulating your data.

My suggestion is after running `df.info()`, for column that is `numeric` but is `objective`, use `pd.to_numeric`

The code as follow:

```
df['Key1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Key1'], errors='coerce')
```

This should helps a lot with your data manipulating later